# MongoDB Optimise Query/Index for querying non-empty subdocuments array

Tags: mongodb

Given this schema

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  last_updated: ISODate,
  sub_items: [
    {
      item_ref: string
    }
  ]
}
```

The sub_items array may not exist, contain multiple items, or maybe empty.

Everyday we need to run the following query on collection with millions of documents

```
db.getCollection('documents').find({
  'sub_items.item_ref': { $exists: true },
  'last_updated': { $gte: ISODate('[yesterday]') }
}).sort({_id: 1 }).limit(100)
```

In order to serve each sub_item individually we have built a "Search after" method, so the next page will be queried by adding `{ _id: {$gte: ObjectId('last_doc_id'})}`, which is also why we're sorting by _id.

We've tried the below Sparse index in various field orders.

```
{'sub_items.item_ref': 1, _id: 1, last_updated: 1 }
```

And Mongo will instead use the _id_1 or an existing last_updated_1 index, resulting in the same 10,000s of documents being analysed in the executionStats.  Hinting the index makes the search even slower, so we can only assume the index is not helping at all.

Is there a better way to define it to improve the response times of this query?

Comment: How many documents are in the collection and how many match the `last_updated` filter? Specifically is the data that you are processing representative of a small percentage overall? Any compelling reason not to do a compound sort on `last_updated` and `_id` (to break ties)?